# how can I phrase the future possible applications of a technology?

Tags: phrase-requests, writing, tenses

I'm writing an overview for a paper, and want to let the reader know part of the outline:

> ...in the last paragraph I want to mention the possible future applications one can reach/accomplish with super conductivity.

Would it be better to phrase this as follows?

> ...I will mention the possible future applications of super conductivity.

Comment: The suggested rephrasing would be better. One doesn't speak of *reaching applications* in normal English, and *accomplishing applications* doesn't sound good to me either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When referring to something you have written, you can drop the *will* or *want*, since you have already done it. This is then usually expressed in the present tense.  Also, whenever possible, try to remove references to yourself (unless you are a subject of the paper):

> The last paragraph mentions possible future applications of super-conductivity.